# Should each IMessageConsumer or IMessageProducer have its own ISession?

Tags: c#, jms, ibm-mq, xms

To make a connection, following objects are needed:

```
IConnection
ISession
IDestination
IMessageConsumer // receiving messages
IMessageProducer // sending messages
```

My case is that I have to connect to 5 queues as `Consumer` and to 5 queues as `Producer`. After reading a lot, I came to the conclusion that `IConnection` should be a single-instance object. But where I start asking questions is; Do I have to create new `ISession` objects for each queue connection? Or can this be a single-instance too?

Quote from [IBM Documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.msc.doc/xms_csess.htm)

> A session is a single threaded context for sending and receiving
>   messages.
>
> If an application must process messages concurrently on more than one
>   thread, the application must create a session on each thread, and then
>   use that session for any send or receive operation within that thread.

So can we conclude that there must be a session for each queue connection? In other words, this means that I have to create 10 `ISession`, 10 `IDestination`, 5 `IMessageConsumer` and 5 `IMessageProducer` objects. Am I right? What's the best practice here?

I've also read somewhere that a new `ISession` creation will make a new TCP connection depending on `SHARECNV` value (if 1, every session is a new TCP connection). So what's the point of using a single-instance `IConnection` then?

**PSEUDO CODE**

**Create connection**

```
var factory = XMSFactoryFactory.GetInstance(XMSC.CT_WMQ);
var cf = factory.CreateConnectionFactory();
cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_HOST_NAME, host);
cf.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_PORT, port);
cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CHANNEL, channel);
cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, qm);
cf.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, XMSC.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
connection = cf.CreateConnection();
```

**Do this 5 times for all incoming messages**

```
ISession session = connection.CreateSession(false, AcknowledgeMode.AutoAcknowledge);
IDestination destination = session.CreateQueue(queuename);
IMessageConsumer consumer = session.CreateConsumer(destination);
consumer.MessageListener = listener;
```

**Do this 5 times for all outgoing messages**

```
ISession session = connection.CreateSession(false, AcknowledgeMode.AutoAcknowledge);
IDestination destination = session.CreateQueue(queuename);
IMessageProducer producer = session.CreateProducer(destination);
```

**Start connection**

```
connection.Start();
```

**Dispose connection**

```
producer?.Close(); //all producers
consumer?.Close(); //all consumers
destination?.Dispose(); //all destinations
session?.Dispose(); //all sessions
connection?.Close();
```

Comment: In general the larger the value of `SHARECNV` the less throughput each session can achieve since that number sessions are funneled over a single single TCP connection.  Conversely setting `SHARECNV(1)` will give the best throughput.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, do you agree with separate sessions for each producer / consumer? @JoshMc

Comment: With `separate` I still mean they are on same thread, but just separate objects

Comment: I think if in the same thread there is no benefit since you are not concurrently producing or consuming with in the same thread so you would not have contention with a single session for that thread.  As you quoted "the application must create **a** session on each thread, and then use **that** session for **any** send or receive operation within that thread.".  I take that to mean a single session for the thread to be used by 1 or many send receive operations in that thread.